# JsonMappingException : Infinite recursion

Tags: java, jackson, jackson2

How to resolve the circular dependency of JSON:

Class:

```
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property = "uniqueID")
final public class TestNode {
    private final String uniqueID;
    private final TestNode testNode; //Circular dependency
}
```

main:

```
private final ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
objectMapper.writeValue(JsonOutputFile, TestNode.class); // Write object to file
```

*If I use JsonIdentityInfo then while writing the object to file in I get results
`{ "uniqueID": "1", "testNode": "1"}`

*If I do not use `JsonIdentityInfo` then I get correct JSON, i.e. testNode is correct but I get following error in that:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Infinite recursion (StackOverflowError) (through reference chain: ["testNode"] ...
```

PS: I'm using the following version:
**Jackson: 3-SNAPSHOT, Java: 8, Spring: 4.3**

Comment: Did you check what exception means?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with the circular dependencies.. I'd resolved it by removing the circular dependencies. Thanks!